# Get nested keys hstore postgres

Tags: postgresql, nested, key, hstore

I'm trying to get the nested key's of the following 2 strings, saved as hstore in an postgresdb:

```
{"values"=>"{\"60\"=>[\"hallo\"], \"63\"=>[\"9\"], \"62\"=>[\"Nein\", \"Vielleicht\"], \"61\"=>[\"Ja\"]}", "comment"=>"[\"hmm\"]"}"},
{"values"=>"{\"60\"=>[\"test?\"], \"63\"=>[\"9\"], \"62\"=>[\"Ja\", \"Nein\"], \"61\"=>[\"Ja\"]}", "comment"=>"[\"kommentar23\"]"}"}
```

to be clear, how can I get all the keys/numbers in sql?

I tried the `akeys` function and get "values", thats fine, thats the first key, but I don't know how to get the nested keys?
I tried with subqueries with no success.

any advice?

Thanks, Patrick

Answer (score 2):

I'd say your hstore looks more like twisted JSON. You can try to replace `=>` with `:` and parse it, for example, with [python json module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or, if you're using 9.3, with [native json methods](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html).

Or you can get [skeys](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/hstore.html), convert it to hstore again and get values.